# What features should I look for when buying a tennis racket?

Tags: tennis, equipment

What are some things that a new tennis player should consider when buying a racket? In this case cost isn't a factor and the player has no idea what to look for.

Comment: Moderator note: Stack Exchange doesn't rule out this kind of somewhat subjective question, but we do have "[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)" guidelines. I think there could be good answers to this question which explain things like the value of larger or smaller racket heads, string tension and the like (if they're relevant, I'm not a tennis player). Answers of the form "Buy Brand X, they're the best" without a justification as to *why* will be deleted in short order.

Comment: For an example of what personally I think is a good subjective question on a different SE site, see [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr/) - the answers explain *how* to make a decision, not which decision should be made so are still relevant today, even though the cameras available in 2010 can't be bought today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a brand new tennis player, it doesn't really matter too much. Since they're new to the sport, they haven't developed a playstyle yet, and so it's impossible to know their strengths and weaknesses, their likes and dislikes, all of which are vital information in choosing a racket.

That being said, we can make some generalizations. Newer players are generally recommended to start with lighter rackets with a larger head size (~110 sq in). Lighter racquets are easier to swing, and a larger head size allows for more leeway in striking the ball, since the contact surface is larger. Start from there and work your way forward. Once the player starts to get a solid hold on the fundamentals and develop their own  playstyle, then they can move forward with selecting a more personalized racket to suit their needs